# Make a docker container use config.v2.json from another

Tags: docker, containers, commit, docker-container

The file `/var/lib/docker/container/config.v2.json` contains settings that I may overwrite without intending to, I can fix them manually but I was wondering if there was a way to make a container use another's **config.v2.json** file.
I've tried stopping the container, and overwriting its current **config.v2.json** with my desired file but when it comes up it overwrites it again with it's original one. Is there any way to achieve this?
Also when I fix it manually using

```
$ docker commit --change='CMD new/stuff/ container image
```

it apparently works but it doesn't show it on **config.v2.json**. Here's an image:

[image]

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: please, share dockerfile of your image

Comment: In general you shouldn't be manually looking at anything in `/var/lib/docker`; it's very implementation-dependent and can change even across systems running the same version of Docker.  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: It's not publicly available. This is what I got using dfimage on appium/appium:latest: https://pastebin.com/JVMp4rnP

For my custom image it only shows:
`
FROM appium/appium:latest
RUN /bin/sh -c /root/wireless_autoconnect.sh \
    && /root/entry_point.sh
RUN /bin/sh -c /root/wireless_autoconnect.sh \
    && /root/entry_point.sh
`

Comment: @DavidMaze I didn't know that. I'm trying to find a way to back up an original container configuration because it's Dockerfile is not public. Commiting changes into it alters the `config.v2.json` and its CMD. I caught that and manually fixed it but there may be times where I'll need to have it load the config from file.

Comment: Is this a configuration file for your application, or a Docker-internal file?  What's in it?

Comment: It's a Docker-internal file, containing the output of `docker inspect`. I'm asking if there's a way to force it upon another container to prevent mistakes and manual corrections. As I said before, copying the file and restarting the container doesn't work.